# Output field separators in awk after substitution in fields

Tags: awk

Is it always the case, after modifying a specific field in `awk`, that information on the output field separator is lost?  What happens if there are multiple field separators and I want them to be recovered?

For example, suppose I have a simple file `example` that contains:

```
a:e:i:o:u
```

If I just run an `awk` script, which takes account of the input field separator, that prints each line in my file, such as running

```
awk -F: '{print $0}' example
```

I will see the original line.  If however I modify one of the fields directly, e.g. with

```
awk -F: '{$2=$2"!"; print $0}' example
```

I do not get back a modified version of the original line, rather I see the fields separated by the default whitespace separator, i.e:

```
a e! i o u
```

I can get back a modified version of the original by specifying OFS, e.g.:

```
awk -F: 'BEGIN {OFS=":"} {$2=$2"!"; print $0}' example
```

In the case, however, where there are multiple potential field separators but in the case of multiple separators is there a simple way of restoring the original separators?

For example, if `example` had both `:` and `;` as separators, I could use `-F":|;"` to process the file but OFS would no be sufficient to restore the original separators in their relative positions.

More explicitly, if we switched to `example2` containing

```
a:e;i:o;u
```

we could use

```
awk -F":|;" 'BEGIN {OFS=":"} {$2=$2"!"; print $0}' example2
```

(or `-F"[:;]"`) to get

```
a:e!:i:o:u
```

but we've lost the distinction between : and ; which would have been maintained if we could recover

```
a:e!;i:o;u
```

Comment: The question is one of the rare good ones here. Why not simply adding a non working example using `-F'[:;]'`. This would make the question perfect - imo

Comment: Explicit example added

Comment: A field separator equivalent of RT would be an obvious GNU extension. I wonder why they don't have it.

Comment: @MichaelVehrs See http://stackoverflow.com/a/38205898/1745001 for the rationale and solution.

Comment: @EdMorton I knew about `split`, but the whole point of using `awk` rather than `perl`, for instance, is the convenience of auto-splitting. And I don't really buy the performance argument either. The hard part of splitting a record into fields is finding the delimiters, not storing them.

Comment: @MichaelVehrs it's not hard it's just unnecessarily time and memory consuming. Awk is expected to be, and is, extremely efficient. If we required storing strings that match an FS for every FS on every line, it's adding cycles for functionality that is almost never needed. Sure you could add flags to turn it on/off but then the field splitting code has to check the flags and you can no longer tell without referring to a flag what the code does. It's much simpler, clearer, and more efficient to simply provide a function you can call to do what you want if/when you want it.

Comment: Also, since this is useful functionality for splitting strings in general you **need** to provide it in the `split()` function and once you have it for `split(<any string>,...)`, you can use it for `split($0,...)` so no point duplicating the functionality in some other way specifically for `$0`, especially given that functionality is rarely needed.

Comment: @EdMorton Since I was not convinced by your arguments, I had a look at the `gawk` sources. As it turns out, they use the same function for explicit split and and auto-split (`re_parse_field` when FS is a regex), and pass in the separator array, which is null unless it was requested. So, if they had FT, there would be no change at all, except that a separator array would be initialized if requested (i.e. if FT was used).

Comment: Again, I am not saying it is a hard thing to do in terms of writing code I am saying it adds cycles to do when executing the code. Populating an array is not free. I feel like I'm just repeating myself so I'm done but please feel free to pursue it with the guys who maintain gawk if you like - they participate in the comp.lang.awk newsgroup and I'm sure would be happy to answer questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use GNU awk for the 4th arg to split() which saves the separators, like RT does for RS:

```
$ awk -F'[:;]' '{split($0,f,FS,s); $2=$2"!"; r=s[0]; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) r=r $i s[i]; $0=r} 1' file
a:e!;i:o;u
```

There is no automatically populated array of FS matching strings because of how expensive it'd be in time and memory to store the string that matches FS every time you split a record into fields. Instead the GNU awk folks provided a 4th arg to split() so you can do it yourself if/when you want it. That is the result of a long conversation a few years ago in the comp.lang.awk newsgroup between experienced awk users and gawk providers before all agreeing that this was the best approach.

See `split()` at https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#String-Functions.